# sed s command & e flag: `echo '$-' | sed 's/-//e'` gives: `sh: $: command not found`

Tags: sed

I'm having a problem with **sed**, when using its '**s**' (search and replace command) with its '**e**' flag, as in

```
sed 's/.../.../e'
```

The problem is that the characters `$`, `(`, and `)` in the standard input appear to confuse it.

---

I first ran into it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567953/how-to-embed-a-bash-function-into-a-sed-expression/569209#569209) and have now boiled it down to this:

```
echo '$-' | sed 's/x//e'               # works when pattern is NOT matched
$-

echo '$-' | sed 's/-//e'               # fails when pattern is matched: gags on $
sh: $: command not found

echo '-' | sed 's/-//e'                # works when $ isn't present

echo '-(' | sed 's/-//e'               # Also fails when '(' or ')' are found
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

echo '(' | sed 's/-//e'                # But works with this
(

echo '$-' | sed 's/-/echo xx/e'        # also fails
sh: xx: command not found

echo '$-' | sed 's/\(-\)/echo '\1'/e'  # also fails
sh: 1: command not found
```

---

**Here's what [the GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-commands-list) says:**

> ### 3.3 The s Command
>
> ...
>
> The s command can be followed by zero or more of the following flags:
>
> ...
>
> **e**
>
> This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into pattern space. If a substitution was made, the command that is found
>   in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its
>   output. A trailing newline is suppressed; results are undefined if the
>   command to be executed contains a NUL character. This is a GNU sed
>   extension.

---

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
Packaged by Debian
```

---

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski, thanks, but no.  What I'm trying to do is to pipe a long list of pathname lines thru a sed filter which operates on some parts of them, even calling a bash function to help rewrite them.  Looks like I might have to figure out another way to do this, as it appears that the e flag doesn't exactly do what it says in the manual.  It seems that the entire output is executed, not just the replacement part.

Comment: OK. For future reference: to avoid such misunderstandings it's good to state your expected output. E.g. I cannot tell what you expected from `echo '$-' | sed 's/-//e'`.

Comment: From your comments I deduce maybe you misinterpreted "pattern space". See [this part of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle): `first, sed reads one line from the input stream, removes any trailing newline, and places it in the pattern space. Then commands are executed`. With `echo '$-' | sed 's/-/echo xx/e'` the pattern space is not `echo xx`. The pattern space is `$-` at first, then `s` does its job and the pattern space becomes `$echo xx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running

```
echo '$-' | sed 's/-//e'
```

removes the `-` from `$-`, leaving just `$`, and the result is run as a shell command, because of `/e`.

The result is the same is if you try to run `$` from the command line:

```
sh: $: command not found
```

And similarly for all other lines.

Comment: Thanks, but in `echo '$-' | sed 's/-/echo xx/e'` I would have thought that the meaning of 'the command that is found in pattern space is executed' would be to execute `echo xx`.  But I think I see what you mean:  It is not executing just the `echo xx`, but rather the entire result, or something like `$$(echo xx)`.  But if so then it makes it very hard to predict what will be executed, and thus this appears to make it insecure in a way too.

Comment: Yes, that's why you seldom find `/e` in sed in practice (unlike a similar but different `/e` in Perl, see [perlop](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer)).