# String Length Always Returns 2 in ZSH Function

Tags: zsh, string, function

I'm trying to bowdlerize email addresses in a fixed length text file by generating a random string the same length as the input. I'm passing the string as a backreference in sed.

To simplify, this script (temp):

```
#!/bin/zsh
IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator
set -f          # disable globbing

#show me the input from the command line
echo $1 ${#1}

function randString() {
    # just echo for demonstration
    echo $1 ${#1}
    # this is the bit I really want:
    # cat /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -cd "[a-z]" | head -c${#1}
}

for line in $(cat $1); do
    echo $line |
        sed "s/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)@\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)\.\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)/$(randString \\1)@$(randString \\2).$(randString \\3)/"

done
```

with this data (temp.txt):

```
me myemail@someserver.com
you youremail@anotherserver.biz
```

run like this:

```
./temp temp.txt
```

gives me this output:

```
temp.txt 8
me myemail 2@someserver 2.com 2
you youremail 2@anotherserver 2.biz 2
```

The problem being that `${#1}` returns 2 no matter what string I feed it. How is the proper string coming back from `$1` while the length from `${#1}` is so very wrong? Is setting `IFS` for the file loop killing my function?

NOTE: I'm on Mac so no GNU extensions.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of diagnostic bits that show what is happening.

With the line `echo rand $1 ${#1} >&2` added to the `randString` function, this is the output:

```
temp.txt 8
rand \1 2
rand \2 2
rand \3 2
me myemail 2@someserver 2.com 2
rand \1 2
rand \2 2
rand \3 2
you youremail 2@anotherserver 2.biz 2
```

By echoing the input to `stderr` with `>&2`, we can see that `randString` is being called with the arguments `\1`, `\2` and `\3` (which have a length of 2), and not the strings that those backreferences were supposed to indicate.

The next test is to preface the call to `sed` with `echo` so we can see what arguments it is getting. The output from that:

```
sed s/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)@\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)\.\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)/\1 2@\2 2.\3 2/
```

With this, `sed` is being told to replace the strings with something like `\1 2`, i.e. a backreference to the input string, followed by a space and the number 2. The strings from the input email address are coming from `sed`, not from the `echo` in the function.

This is because the the command substitutions in the string (the `$(...)` expansions) are processed by `zsh` before the string is passed to `sed` as an argument.  In order to get the input strings passed to the function, you'll need `sed` to call the shell function. But there may not be a way to do that in [the default the version of `sed`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567953/how-to-embed-a-bash-function-into-a-sed-expression).

---

Edited to add: a quick script for munging email addresses that is mostly `zsh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
setopt extendedglob

coproc cat /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -cd "[:lower:]" 

getRand (){
  print -r -- ${1//(#m)[[:alnum:]]/$(read -psk var;echo $var)}
}

while read line; do
  print -r -- ${line/(#m)[[:alnum:]](#c2,)@[[:alnum:]](#c2,).[[:alnum:]](#c2,)/$(getRand ${MATCH})}
done < ${1:?}
```

Comment: Sadly your regex rejects <john.doe+job_search@yahoo-inc.com>

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #!/bin/zsh
> IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator
> set -f          # disable globbing
> ```

`zsh -f`, like `csh -f` is to skip reading startup files, not to disable globbing (except when in sh/ksh emulation), for which you need `set -o noglob` or `set +o glob` (or variants with `setopt`/`unsetopt`).

You'd use `set -f` in other Bourne-like shells to work around their misfeature by  which globbing is performed upon unquoted expansions. But zsh doesn't have that misfeature as the `globsubst` option is disabled by default (when not in `sh`/`ksh` emulation mode).

> ```
> #show me the input from the command line
> echo $1 ${#1}
> ```

It should be `print -r -- $1 $#1` or `echo -E - $1 $#1` or `printf '%s\n' "$1 $#1"` or that won't work properly with values of `$1` that contain `\`s or some values that start with `-`.

> ```
> function randString() {
> ```

I'd choose between the `randString() ...` Bourne syntax or `function randString {` Korn syntax, but not use that combination (but then it's only a matter of taste).

> ```
>     # cat /dev/urandom | LC_ALL=C tr -cd "[a-z]" | head -c${#1}
> ```

Con`cat`enating a single file makes little sense.

Beware that with most `tr` implementations, `tr -cd "[a-z]"` would also produce `[` and `]` characters.

```
$ echo '[]123ab' | tr -cd '[a-z]'
[]ab
$ echo '[]123ab' | tr -cd a-z
ab
```

> ```
> }
>
> for line in $(cat $1); do
> ```

That's not how you process text in shells. See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/22565)

> ```
>     echo $line |
>         sed "s/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)@\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)\.\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)/$(randString \\1)@$(randString \\2).$(randString \\3)/"
> ```

In there, the shell will perform the `$(...)` expansions before calling `sed`. `randString \\1` calls `randString` with a literal `\1` as argument, so you end up calling `sed` with a `s/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)@\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)\.\([a-zA-Z0-9]\{2,\}\)/\12@\22.\32/` argument.

Also beware that what `[a-z]` and co. match depends on the locale.

Here, you should rather run one invocation of a text processing utility, preferably one that can generate random strings. Something like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
exec perl -Tpe 's{\w{2,}@\w{2,}\.\w{2,}}{
  $& =~ s/\w/chr 96 + rand(26)/ger}ge' -- "$@"
```

Here using `sh` instead of `zsh` as `sh` is more than enough and call `perl` to do the text processing and generate random strings in a much much simpler and more efficient manner.

Or write a `perl` script instead:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl --

while (<<>>) {
  s{\w{2,}@\w{2,}\.\w{2,}}{$& =~ s/\w/chr 96 + rand(26)/ger}ge;
  print;
}
```

Here using `<<>>` instead of `<>`. The `-p` option implies a `<>` loop, which allows passing things like `ls|` to process the output of `ls` instead of the file called `ls|`, but that's [rather dangerous](/q/170013). Using the `-T` option somewhat mitigates the security issues, `<<>>` addresses it.

Doing something similar in `zsh` internally is possible but would not be pretty.

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/mathfunc
zmodload zsh/mapfile
set -o extendedglob

pattern='[[:alnum:]](#c2,)@[[:alnum:]](#c2,).[[:alnum:]](#c2,)'
for file do
  print -rn -- ${mapfile[$file]//(#m)$~pattern/${MATCH//(#m)[[:alnum:]]/${(L)$(( [##36] rand48() * 26 + 9))}}}
done
```

Here using:

- `$mapfile[file]` to load the contents of files
- zsh's own glob operators to do the matching instead of regexps
- `rand48()` to generate random numbers, here between 10 and 35 in base 36 to output letters `A` to `Z`, converted to lowercase with the `L` parameter expansion flag.

Comment: You covered much more than I asked and instead gave me what I need. Thank you.